# Taylor's expansion at $x=x_0$

Tags: analysis

Is Taylor series expansion $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}  (x-x_0)^{(n)}$ equal to $f(x_0)$  when $x=x_0$?  How do you see it from the expansion?

Comment: Yes. $(x_0-x_0)^n=0 \forall n, n \ne 0$

Comment: Explicit the first three terms of the summation, this is not untractable.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if $x=x_0$ then $(x-x_0)^n=0$ unless $n=0$ in which case $$\lim_{x\to x_0} (x-x_0)^0=\lim_{x\to x_0} 1=1$$ so $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n=\frac{f^{(0)}(x_0)}{0!}\times1=f(x_0)$$